# Closing file messes with std::getline() and cin?

Tags: c++

I have a program that was working fine until I closed a file before using `std::getline()`.  The `close(fileTest)` line causes the while loop to repeat forever without asking the user for input.  It just skips the `getline()`, even on the first loop.

I spent about 2 hours trying to figure this out so I know all about the buffer and `cin>>` behavior.  I finally ended up commenting out lines before the `getline()` call and found out what was happening.

Obviously I came across lots of duplicate questions about the input buffer and I know that files work similarly but I don't understand why `getline()` is messing up when I am explicitly requesting data from `cin` or why *closing* the file is what triggers it.

Any idea why this is happening or a workaround (other than just leaving the file open forever)?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

char *fileName;
struct stat fileStatus;

int main(int arc, char **argv)
{
    fileName = argv[1];
    string menuChoice = "1";

    //TODO: remove this. Testing only
    fileName = (char *)"test";

    //print message for no args
    if (fileName == NULL)
    {
        printf("NO file selected\nUsage: fileutil <filename>\n\n");
    }

    //Make sure we can actually open the file
    int fileTest;
    if (fileTest = (open(fileName, O_RDONLY)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Failed to open file");
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    close(fileTest);  //THIS MESSES UP cin IF NOT COMMENTED OUT?????

    //main menu loop
    while (true)
    {
        //display the menu and handle options
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::getline(cin, menuChoice);
        //view file contents
        if (menuChoice == "1")
        {
        }
        //display file info
        else if (menuChoice == "2")
        {
        }
        //change file permissions
        else if (menuChoice == "3")
        {
        }
        //copy file
        else if (menuChoice == "4")
        {            
        }
        //exit
        else if (menuChoice == "5")
        {
            printf("Thank you. Exiting program...\n\n");
            return (0);
        }
        //handle invalid responses
        else
            printf("Invalid response\n\n");
    }

    return 0;
} //end main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `fileTest = (open(fileName, O_RDONLY)) < 0` comparison is performed prior to assignment because it has higher precedence. So `fileTest` will not hold the result of `open` invocation but rather result of comparison which may be the same value as one of the standard input / output handles (which are typically 0, 1, 2). So subsequent `close` will close standard input while handle returned by `open` is lost. Also result of `open` should be checked against -1.

So the rule of thumb is to never use result of assignment operator:

```
auto const fileTest{::open(fileName, O_RDONLY)};
if (-1 == fileTest)
```